# set transparent border to CComboBox control

Tags: winapi, mfc, window, win32gui

I am trying to set transparent border of `CComboBox` control.
For other control like `CEdit` it is possible to do so using control properties but I am unable to find any solution for `CComboBox`. I want result something like shown in image.

[image]

Comment: Refer to: [How to remove edit box border in Simple type comboxbox.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14247099-fefa-4230-9e18-dcb8281223d2/how-to-remove-edit-box-border-in-simple-type-comboxbox?forum=vcmfcatl)

Comment: I am facing some sort of crash here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a little piece of code, I hope it help you:

```
// YourComboBox.h : header file
class CYourComboBox : public CComboBox
{
public:
    CEdit      m_edit;
    CListBox   m_listbox;

protected:
    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
    afx_msg void OnDestroy();
    ...
};

// YourComboBox.cpp : implementation file
HBRUSH CYourComboBox::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT)
    {
        //Edit control
        if (m_edit.GetSafeHwnd() == NULL)
            m_edit.SubclassWindow(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
    }
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX)
    {
        //ListBox control
        if (m_listbox.GetSafeHwnd() == NULL)
            m_listbox.SubclassWindow(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
    }

    RemoveEditBorder();

    HBRUSH hbr = CComboBox::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    return hbr;
}

void CYourComboBox::OnDestroy()
{
    if (m_edit.GetSafeHwnd() != NULL)
        m_edit.UnsubclassWindow();
    if (m_listbox.GetSafeHwnd() != NULL)
        m_listbox.UnsubclassWindow();

    CComboBox::OnDestroy();
}

void CYourComboBox::RemoveEditBorder()
{
    m_edit.ModifyStyle(WS_BORDER, 0);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of below fields?                                                                                  CEdit      m_edit;
CListBox   m_listbox;

Comment: It's variable member corresponding to edit and to list of `CComboBox`. Agree, you can simply it as you wish, for instance, you don't need `m_listbox` in your case.

Comment: sorry, this works but it has some crash in it

Comment: Where is crashing ?

Comment: Do you have any debugger message ?